# How to programmatically sign a project in c sharp

Tags: envdte

I am creating projects from a template using DTE. I want the projects to be signed by a particular .snk file. How to do it programmatically??

please help..!!

Thanks,
Girish

Answer (score 1):

What I did is add a new Addin project into my solution and by adding this code:

```
    public void OnConnection(object application, ext_ConnectMode connectMode, objec addInInst,   ref Array custom)
    {
        _applicationObject = (DTE2)application;
        _addInInstance = (AddIn)addInInst;
        SetSign(_applicationObject);
    }

     public void SetSign(DTE2 app)
     {
         Solution solution = app.Solution;
         foreach (Project proj in solution.Projects)
         {
            if (null != proj.Properties && null != proj.Properties.Item("SignAssembly"))
            {
               Property projProperty = proj.Properties.Item("SignAssembly");
               bool signed = (bool)projProperty.Value;
               if (!signed)
               {
                  proj.Properties.Item("AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile").Value = @"C:\Projects\ClassLibrary1\Addins\Tools\mykeyfile.pfx";
                  proj.Properties.Item("SignAssembly").Value = true;
                }
                proj.Save();
             }
          }
       }
```